# Find if asian typo are installed

Tags: linux, localization

I need to find out if asian typo are installed on my Linux VPS.

Is there a way i can find it out?

I guess to install it i can run `yum groupinstall "Chinese Support"` but how to find out if they are already installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You an use `yum grouplist <groupname>` to find out

```
yum grouplist 'Arabic Support'
. . .
Installed Language Groups:
Arabic Support [ar]
```

In this case it says that the group is installed

```
yum grouplist 
. . .
Available Language Groups:
Chinese Support [zh]
```

In this case it is Available and therefore not installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was just wondering if locale and language groups are the same since i find zh_HK, zh_* if i do `locale -a`

Comment: Besides there are dependencies like pulse audio etc.. can they be excluded? Thanks